# Angular class change directive doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I want to add a directive that will do something when an element class is changed.

My directive is:

```
(function (angular) {

angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myClassWatch', myClassWatch);

function myClassWatch() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return element.attr('class');
            }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                debugger;
                if(oldValue !== newValue)
                    console.log('class changed from ' + oldValue + ' to ' + newValue);
            });
        }
    }
}
})(angular);
```

The html is:

```
<div class="top-icons-item popup-container popup-link-container" my-class-watch>

</div>
```

I do some actions elsewhere that toggles the class "open" in my div element - it is visible in the html - yet the debugger is never called (also no console logs of course). I can see that the link function is called on page load and the debugger also stops, but thats only on page load and not afterwards when I actually do actions that adds another class.

I have read several issued here before including [Directive : $observe, class attribute change caught only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679534/directive-observe-class-attribute-change-caught-only-once) but I can't understand why I don't get the same result. What can I do to try check why this occures?

Update: The class change is made using jQuery not in a controller but in an old jquery watches code. May this be cause? could angular be unaware of class change when its not done from an angular code?

Comment: Have look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085553/angularjs-watch-element-visibilty

Comment: You should use `$observe` and not `$watch`

Comment: But I read in the post that I added that observe will only work once.

Comment: I can't see why your code isn't working, see this working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cg0h5jgf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your jQuery code into `$apply`.

It similar to you are making changes to `$scope` out of angular context`(jquery ajax, setTimeout, etc)`. Use `$apply` to make angular know about the changes done.

```
    angular.element(document.getElementById('app')).injector().invoke(['$compile', '$rootScope', function($compile, $rootScope) {
       $rootScope.$apply(function() {
           //your jquery code goes here...
           var a = document.getElementById('abc');
           angular.element(a).addClass('hello');
       });
    }]);
```

Comment: No. You are externally triggers digest cycle to make angular known about your changes. It is similar to ng-click callback function. It also triggers digest cycle.

Comment: It also uses $apply internally.